# Applying GroupWise 'Softmax' on a dataframe and updating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataset where each unique id is repeated three or two times with different scores ordered by rank for each.

```
     Manufacture_Id  Score  Rank
0           id_1     93     1
1           id_1     91     2
2           id_1     86     3
3           id_2     88     1
4           id_2     73     2
5           id_2     72     3
6           id_3     34     1
7           id_3     24     2
```

I want to create a new column in same dataset as **Score2** which applies **softmax** function on each unique **Manufacture_Id** on scores and give their respective softmax scores.

The idea is to get the complete score for each id to be summing up to 1 like probability. Below is the expected output.

> Note - The Scores2 value may vary from the one given below. But they
> should sum to 1 for each id group.

```
 Manufacture_Id  Score  Rank  Score2
0           id_1     93     1    0.88
1           id_1     91     2    0.12
2           id_1     86     3    0.00
3           id_2     88     1    1.00
4           id_2     73     2    0.00
5           id_2     72     3    0.00
6           id_3     34     1    1.00
7           id_3     24     2    0.00
```

Below is the sample data and a sample code for softmax for reference.

```
#Sample Data

import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["id_1",93,1],
    ["id_1",91,2],
    ["id_1",86,3],
    ["id_2",88,1],
    ["id_2",73,2],
    ["id_2",72,3],
    ["id_3",34,1],
    ["id_2",24,2],
       
]

#dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Manufacture_Id', 'Score', 'Rank'])

#Sample code an an array for softmax

from scipy.special import softmax

# define data
data1 = [93,91,86]
# calculate softmax
result1 = softmax(data1)
# report the probabilities
print(result1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
test['Score2'] = test.groupby('Manufacture_Id')['Score'].transform(softmax)
print (test)
  Manufacture_Id  Score  Rank        Score2
0           id_1     93     1  8.800902e-01
1           id_1     91     2  1.191073e-01
2           id_1     86     3  8.025384e-04
3           id_2     88     1  9.999996e-01
4           id_2     73     2  3.059022e-07
5           id_2     72     3  1.125351e-07
6           id_3     34     1  1.000000e+00
7           id_2     24     2  1.603810e-28
```

Comment: thanks! just curious if there is a faster way to do this?

Comment: @Deb - Hmm, so it is expected, because you call function for each group. And if many groups in large DataFrame then it is slowier.