# Apply a softmax function on groupby in the same pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking to apply the following softmax function from https://machinelearningmastery.com/softmax-activation-function-with-python/

```
from scipy.special import softmax
# define data
data = [1, 3, 2]
# calculate softmax
result = softmax(data)
# report the probabilities
print(result)
[0.09003057 0.66524096 0.24472847]
```

I am trying to apply this to a dataframe which is split by groups, and return the probabilites row by row for a group.
My dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'EventNo': ['10','10','12','12','12'],
    'Name': ['Joe','Jack','John','James','Jim'],
    'Rating':[30,32,2.5,3,4],
    }
             
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
    EventNo Name    Rating
0   10       Joe       30.0
1   10       Jack      32.0
2   12       John      2.5
3   12       James     3.0
4   12       Jim       4
```

In this instance there are two different events (`10` and `12`) where for event `10` the values are `data = [30,32]` and event `12` `data = [2.5,3,4]`

My expected result would be a new column `probabilities` with the results:

```
    EventNo Name    Rating     Probabilities
0   10       Joe       30.0       0.1192
1   10       Jack      32.0       0.8807
2   12       John      2.5         0.1402
3   12       James     3.0        0.2312
4   12       Jim       4          0.6285
```

Any help on how to do this on all groups in the dataframe would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904709/applying-groupwise-softmax-on-a-dataframe-and-updating-a-new-column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `groupby` followed by `transform` which returns results indexed by the original dataframe. A simple way to do it would be

```
df["Probabilities"] = df.groupby('EventNo')["Rating"].transform(softmax)
```

The result is

```
  EventNo   Name  Rating  Probabilities
0      10    Joe    30.0       0.119203
1      10   Jack    32.0       0.880797
2      12   John     2.5       0.140244
3      12  James     3.0       0.231224
4      12    Jim     4.0       0.628532
```