# How can I compute the value of softmax function on only a couple of Dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following Dataframe:

| Index | Plassering | Average FGrating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22943 | 1 | 100.43 |
| 22944 | 2 | 93.5 |
| 22945 | 3 | 104.6 |
| 22746 | 4 | 101.3 |
| 22947 | 1 | 102.05 |
| 22948 | 2 | 107.35 |
| 22949 | 3 | 109.12 |

I am trying to apply the `softmax` function for the `Average FGrating` column, for the entire DataFrame, while the `Plassering` values are increasing. This means that I want to apply `softmax` for the first four rows in the DataFrame, then for the next 3 rows, separately, and so on.

The entire DataFrame, having about 5000 rows, is structured like this.

My first attempt is to cycle through the rows of this DataFrame, using `iterrows()` and, while `Plassering` is increasing, the `Average FGrating` value is added to a list. When the `Plassering` value is smaller that the value from the previous row, I compute the `softmax` passing the list as a parameter, then empty the list and the cycle goes on. However, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) that it is not a good idea, performance-wise.

Do you have any better ideas than mine?

Comment: Duplicated 2 questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68904709/applying-groupwise-softmax-on-a-dataframe-and-updating-a-new-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480544/apply-a-softmax-function-on-groupby-in-the-same-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a groupby transformation. First generate the groups, then apply your softmax:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import softmax

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your df here

groups = df["Plassering"].diff().lt(0).cumsum()
out = df["Average FGrating"].groupby(groups).transform(softmax)
```

results:

```
>>> groups
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
Name: Plassering, dtype: int32
>>> out
0    0.014684
1    0.000014
2    0.950254
3    0.035048
4    0.000726
5    0.145437
6    0.853837
Name: Average FGrating, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you both you and @RomanPerekhrest for your answers. I chose yours because it's a bit easier to understand by me.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on consecutive differences of `Plassering` values (cumulated as separate groups) and [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) operation:

```
from scipy.special import softmax

df['soft_max'] = (df.groupby(df['Plassering'].diff().ne(1).cumsum())
                  ['Average FGrating'].transform(softmax))
```

---

```
   Index  Plassering  Average FGrating  soft_max
0  22943           1            100.43  0.014684
1  22944           2             93.50  0.000014
2  22945           3            104.60  0.950254
3  22746           4            101.30  0.035048
4  22947           1            102.05  0.000726
5  22948           2            107.35  0.145437
6  22949           3            109.12  0.853837
```